# How to use `Dir` to reference directories outside the working directory

Tags: ruby, directory, working-directory

The closest issue I could find on Stack Overflow was "[Path outside of project, Ruby Dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818446/path-outside-of-project-ruby-dir)", but the user appears to have been in the wrong development environment.

My issue is that the `Dir` class only gives information relative to the working directory.  For instance, if I'm in `C:/Users/john/Developer` and this directory only has two subdirectories `A` and `B` then

```
$ ruby -e "p Dir['*']"
```

will return `["A", "B"]`.  This seems intended, but what if there is a directory `C:/Users/jane/Developer/C` that I need to run a command in using a script in `C:/Users/john/Developer`?

Running

```
Dir.chdir('C:/Users/jane/Developer/C') { %x[lerna clean] }
```

returns the error:

```
-e:1:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_s_chdir - C:/Users/jane/Developer/C (Errno::ENOENT)
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way to access directories outside of the working directory using the `Dir` class?  It seems absurd to have to require scripts to be written at a root level.

Note, using `%x[]` to run the command in `C:/Users/jane/Developer/C` also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure you're not making a typo? What if you go into the command prompt and type `cd C:\Users\jane\Developer\C`? `Dir.chdir` should work just like `cd` in your command prompt.

Comment: As mentioned by @Casper, it shouldn't be a problem if the folder exists *and* you're allowed to access it as `john`. You could try it step by step : `ruby -e "p Dir['C:/*']"`, then `ruby -e "p Dir['C:/Users/*']"` and so on. My guess is that `ruby -e "p Dir['C:/Users/jane/*']"` will return an empty list because you're not allowed to access anything inside.

Comment: It looks like you're misunderstanding Dir and `chdir`'s purpose: Dir is a way to get the files and directories in the path you tell it; It won't execute, it just returns paths to those resources. `chdir` changes the directory and with a block lets you run code in the block in the new working directory. It's always your job to figure out what your current working directory is, and how to reference a running script elsewhere. Ruby's [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/File.html) class has "`*path`" methods to help you do figure out full paths and makes this stuff easier.